# WebView not not opening flutter net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, android-webview, firebase-dynamic-links

I am working on a flutter app that require to show a webview.

##### When I navigate to the Webview widget, It shows this.

[image: firebase dynamic link not opening in webview]

The InitialURL of the webview widget is a `firebase dynamic link for android`

- I have configure the firebase dynamic link package according to the [flutter fire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/overview/)
- As for the Webview, I am using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

This is the part of my code where I open the Webview

```html
SafeArea(
                    child: Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        backgroundColor: Palette.primary,
                        elevation: 0,
                        title: Text(
                          "Payment Checkout",
                          style: Styles.designText(
                              bold: false, size: 14, color: Palette.light),
                        ),
                      ),
                      body: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: WebViewPlus(
                          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                            // controller.loadUrl("https://s.htr.cm/9iAq");
                          },
                          initialUrl:
                              "https://mesomb.hachther.com/en/web/payment/CM/?widget=253",
                          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
```

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve this problem??